# What does "public Weatherman(Integer... zips) {" mean in java

Tags: java, constructor

I am trying to read some Java code from a tutorial, I don't understand the line:

```
 public Weatherman(Integer... zips) {
```

- I don't understand what the ... represents if it was just (Integer zips) I would understand that there is a variable of class Integer called zips. But the ... are confusing me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those are "varargs," syntactic sugar that allows you to invoke the constructor in the following ways:

```
new Weatherman()
new Weatherman(98115);
new Weatherman(98115, 98072);
new Weatherman(new Integer[0]);
```

Under the covers the arguments are passed to the constructor as an array, but you do not need to construct an array to invoke it.

Answer (score 5):

That’s a “vararg”. It can handle any number of `Integer` arguments, i.e.

```
new Weatherman(1);
```

is just as valid as

```
new Weatherman();
```

or

```
new Weatherman(1, 7, 12);
```

Within the method you access the parameters as an `Integer` array.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing the [varargs feature](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) of Java, available since Java 1.5.

zips is an array of Integer inside the constructor, but the constructor can be called with a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html):

> You can use a construct called varargs to pass an arbitrary number of values to a method. You use varargs when you don't know how many of a particular type of argument will be passed to the method. It's a shortcut to creating an array manually (the previous method could have used varargs rather than an array).
>
> To use varargs, you follow the type of the last parameter by an ellipsis (three dots, ...), then a space, and the parameter name. The method can then be called with any number of that parameter, including none.

```
public Polygon polygonFrom(Point... corners) {
    int numberOfSides = corners.length;
    double squareOfSide1, lengthOfSide1;
    squareOfSide1 = (corners[1].x - corners[0].x)*(corners[1].x - corners[0].x) 
        + (corners[1].y - corners[0].y)*(corners[1].y - corners[0].y) ;
    lengthOfSide1 = Math.sqrt(squareOfSide1);
    // more method body code follows that creates 
    // and returns a polygon connecting the Points
}
```

> You can see that, inside the method, corners is treated like an array. The method can be called either with an array or with a sequence of arguments. The code in the method body will treat the parameter as an array in either case.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember good it is used when there is a variable number of parameters